# VBA: Which code is more efficient for unhiding sheets?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to get a better understanding of VBA and make sure I'm making my code as efficient as possible, even if it's a marginal difference.

Below I have two working procedures that will unhide Sheets 4 and higher in a workbook. Both approaches seem pretty straight forward, but I'm curious which one is more efficient from a process standpoint and if possible, could you explain why one is superior to the other?

```
For i = 4 To Worksheets.Count
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Visible = True
Next
```

vs

```
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Index > 3 Then
        ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
    End If
Next
```

Comment: This question is off-topic for SO. You should post on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: First one is simpler and so I'd go for that one.

Comment: Also the second one has a potential problem if you have other sheet types (eg chart sheets) in your workbook: for example [Sheet1][Chart1][Sheet2] - here `Index` for Sheet2 is 3, but it's not the 3rd *worksheet*.  First example could also give odd results depending on where it's located in the workbook (`ThisWorkbook` vs a regular code module)

Comment: Critiquing how I asked the question doesn't really answer the question...

Which code has less steps/runs faster.

Similar to how index/match is more efficient than a vlookup.

Comment: For the record no one is *critiquing how you asked the question*. People are trying to guide you and make sure you have an enjoyable experience now and in the future on this site, by making sure you ask questions that are on-topic ([help/on-topic]). The SO system can, and will, throttle and question-ban users that consistently fail to ask well-received questions. Breathe, SO folks aren't here to chew anyone's head off, and everyone *is* trying to help you, one way or another. Anyway.. *you got 2 horses, race them!* ;-)

Comment: Yep, just trying to be helpful here....

Comment: Thank you for the comments, you (Tim) and Mathieu have both been helpful, my comment was directed at "pnuts".

He seems to be the only person who didn't understand the intent behind what I was asking.

My question may be in the negative, but I got the answer I was looking for and can apply what I learned now towards future scripts; so all in all I'd call it a win. Thank you SO folks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried timing each to see which works faster?  A simple timer is as follows:

```
Dim a as Double, b as Double

a = Timer

‘Your code goes in here

b = Timer

msgbox b - a
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Both seem to have some variance, and return between 0 and .0078
My guess would be that the 1st one should be more efficient since it's not checking the first few workbooks.

Comment: You will need to loop the test enough times to get the run time up to at least a few seconds to get realistic results (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18777673/445425) (`Timer` has the same resolution issue as `getTickCount`)